# How to structure angularjs services to consume a REST API?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I am wondering about the best way to structure the services / factories in an Angular app to consume a REST API. I know about `$resource` but I don't want to use it since my API is a bit special and not just CRUD on `/api/resource/:id` etc.

There are two basic ways I can think of and I'm not sure which is the better once. I guess there are up- and downsides for both and that's why I'm asking.

**Option 1**

Have an API factory with many methods for each model. That would look something like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['$http'])

.factory('apiService', function() {
  var o = {
    posts: [],
    comments: []
  };
  o.getAllPosts = function() {
    return $http.get('/api/v1/posts').success(function(data){
      angular.copy(data, o.posts);
    });
  };
  o.getAllComments = function() {
    return $http.get('/api/v1/comments').success(function(data){
      angular.copy(data, o.comments);
    });
  };
})

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, apiService) {
  // Get all posts
  $scope.posts = apiService.getAllPosts();
  // Get all comments
  $scope.comments = apiService.getAllComments();
});
```

**Option 2**

Have a factory for every data model. Something like this:

```
myModule.factory('posts', ['$http', function($http){
  var o = {
    posts: [],
    post: {}
  };
  o.getAll = function() {
    return $http.get('/api/v1/posts').success(function(data){
      angular.copy(data, o.posts);
    });
  };
  o.getOne = function(params) {
    return $http.get('/api/v1/posts/'+params.hash_id).success(function(data){
      angular.copy(data, o.post);
    });
  };
  o.create = function(post) {
    return $http.post('/api/v1/posts', post).success(function(data){
      o.posts.unshift(data);
    });
  };
  return o;
}]);

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, posts) {
  // Get all posts
  $scope.posts = posts.getAll();
});
```

What is the better way to handle this and why?

Comment: Hard to believe that your API is so special that you cannot use `$resource`. Maybe it's not a REST API after all.

Comment: You are probably right. I started looking into it again and I might have it structured badly. I have nested resources where one form creates multiple things. But I will take that complexity out of the API and into the backend.